# How to create pg_background extension in postgres 9.6?

Tags: postgresql

I am in a process of implementing pg_background in postgres When I type create extension pg_background It is giving me the following error: could not open extension control file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/share/extension/pg_background.control": No such file or directory.

Please help me how to install pg_background to work.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I am using pg_background to implement autonomous transaction.

Comment: Do you have such a file? Do you have the pg_background extension installed on your machine?

Comment: No I dont have that file. No I dont have pg_background extension installed please guide me creating extension for pg_background @RichardHuxton

Comment: Well, you haven't told anyone (1) how you installed PostgreSQL, (2) what extensions are listed in your installer, (3) what this pg_background extension is and where it can be found (4) what steps you have taken to install it, (5) what errors / problems you encountered.

Comment: Richard I was asking how to install pg_background this what my query is

Comment: You're supposed to say what you've tried and what didn't work for you.

Comment: I tried Create extension pg_background but it did not worked for me.Getting error called  : could not open extension control file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/share/extension/pg_background.control": No such file or directory.

Comment: I want and show the file but it does not exists Please guide me how to install pg_background and steps to install it

Comment: 1. Google for the "pg_background" project, 2. Actually read the instructions and try to follow them. 3. Post a question once you have tried and have a problem.